# Как передать значение Null в NativeQuery при изменении данных в Базе

Tags: kotlin, hibernate, запрос

С Фронта передается

```
<b-form-select-option :value ="null"> Не выбрано </b-form-select-option>


@RestController
@PutMapping("${DICT_EBK_FUNC_TYPES}/LevelId/update")
   fun UpDateDictEbkChildrenLevelId(@RequestParam id: Int, @RequestParam budgetLevelId: Int?){
       return dictService.getDictEbkChildrenLevelId(id, budgetLevelId) }

@Service
fun getDictEbkChildrenLevelId(id: Int,  budgetLevelId: Int?) {
       return  dictEbkFuncVedomRepository.upDateChildrenLevelId(id, budgetLevelId )}

@Query
@Transactional
   @Modifying
   @Query(
       value = "UPDATE public.dict_ebk_func\n" +
               "\tSET  budget_level_id=?2\n" +
               "\tWHERE id in  (WITH RECURSIVE node_rec AS (\n" +
               "   (SELECT 1 AS depth, ARRAY[id] AS path, *\n" +
               "    FROM   public.dict_ebk_func \n" +
               "    WHERE  id=?1\n" +
               "   )    \n" +
               "    UNION ALL\n" +
               "    SELECT r.depth + 1, r.path || n.id, n.*\n" +
               "    FROM   node_rec r \n" +
               "    JOIN   public.dict_ebk_func n ON n.gr = r.gr\n" +
               "   \t\t   and (n.pgr = r.pgr or r.pgr is null)\n" +
               "\t\t   and (n.abp = r.abp or r.abp is null)\n" +
               "\t\t   and (n.prg = r.prg or r.prg is null)\n" +
               "\t       and (n.ppr = r.ppr or r.ppr is null)\n" +
               "\t       and n.type = r.type + 1\n" +
               ")\n" +
               "SELECT id\n" +
               "FROM   node_rec\n" +
               "ORDER  BY path);", nativeQuery = true
   )
   fun upDateChildrenLevelId(id: Int, budgetLevelId: Int?)
```

ОШИБКА ПРИ ВХОДЕ В КОНТРОЛЛЕР!!!!!`Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Integer'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "null"`
О

В базе Колонка INTEGER, Null допускается.
Если число, Сохраняется нормально!

Comment: budget_level_id=?2  у вас должна быть строка budget_level_id=NULL в результирующем SQL. разбирайтесь с передачей и преобразованием параметров в NativeQuery. я бы сделал параметр budgetLevelId: string и в случае пустого значения заполнял бы его дефолтным значением 'NULL'

Comment: спасибо, попробую